# Big Sur Webserver PHP not exxecuting

Tags: php, ios, apache2

I have a mini Mac and have just updated to Big Sur (is that pronounced Big Sewer?)

The local webserver works

sudo apachectl -t gives Syntax OK

Path to httpd.conf is /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4

I changed DocumentRoot successfully here.
(There is another httpd.confg but it doesn't change the DocumentRoot.)

Php7 is installed
php -v  gives PHP 7.3.24 Zend Engine v3.3.24

Command line PHP works and displays data from MySQL database correctly.

I have a home.php page. The HTML part displays correctly. The php section  is ignored.
If I check the Source Code in my browser it includes the PHP section.

When I first started to get this working, my browser wanted to download home.php so I'm part way there.

I tried to follow :
https://wpbeaches.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-11-big-sur-and-earlier-macos/

Things I have changed:

/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf

```
    Changed path in 
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Alison/Sites"
    <Directory "/Users/Alison/Sites">

    Removed # from
    Include /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

    LoadModule php7_module /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so has no #

    <IfModule php7>
    Include /private/etc/apache2/other/php7.conf
    </IfModule>
```

/private/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
     Added 
     <IfModule php7>
     Include /private/etc/apache2/other/php7.conf
     </IfModule>


     <FilesMatch \.phph$>
     SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
     </FilesMatch>
```

Things I can't do

```
        sudo service apache2 restart
            Sudo: service: command not found
            
        sudo a2dismod mpm_event 
            Sudo: a2dismod: command not found
            
        sudo a2enmod mpm_event  
            Sudo: a2enmod: command not found
```

because Big Sur dosen't have a2dismod, a2enmod or service.